# why python3 lru_cache doesn't offer an put and query method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, lru

here is my situation, the `is_exist` function has performance matter.

```py
def is_exist(link :str) -> bool:
    if query_db(link) is True:
         return True
    return False

def process(link: str)
   if is_exist(link) is True:
       return
   # do something
   # put result to database
```

LRU Cache is a good solution, but after struggle hours i found lru_cache doesn't meet my requirments. What i want like this:

```py
def is_exist(link :str) -> bool:
    if query_db(link) is True:
         return True
    return False

def process(link: str)
   if lru_cache.query(link) is True:
      return

   if is_exist(link) is True:
       lru_cache.add(link)
       return
   # do something
   # put result to database
```

The LRU Cache in functiontools is a decorator. It doesn't have a query method. If I use `@lru_cache` decorates `is_exist` some link will be processed repeatedly when `is_exist` return false.

PS: put result to db is async

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you actually want to happen? The answer by @sophros is the appropriate use of the `@lru_cache` here, but that doesn't seem to be what you want. Do you want to decorate *both* functions (I doubt it, since it doesn't return anything useful)?

Comment: I guess the issue is that if False is returned from is_exists the first time, with lru_cache that value will always be returned even once link has been written to DB - i.e. OP needs a way to invalidate the lrucache when link didn't initially exist but then has been created in the DB.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I have commented sophros's answer.

Comment: avoid the issue by not having two functions - combine into a single lru_cache-d function, see my answer

Comment: Your title asks why the feature isn't there. Your descriptions asks how to work around it. Which of the two are you actually interested in?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yeah. I am interested in both of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`functools.lru_cache` only caches *results* but not exceptions. This means functions should raise an exception in any situation that must be re-evaluated later on.

```
@lru_cache
def is_exist(link: str) -> bool:
    if query_db(link):
         return True   # added to cache
    raise LookupError  # ignored by cache
```

This allows the client function to check – with cache – but still insert missing entries.

```
def process(link: str)
   try:
       is_exist(link)
   except LookupError:
       # do something
       # put result to database
```

Answer (score 0):

### Typical use of `lru_cache`

I am not sure why you are not applying `lru_cache` as decorator:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def is_exist(link :str) -> bool:
    if query_db(link) is True:
         return True
    return False
```

As long as the repeated calls to `is_exist` are going to use the same argument `link` the cache is going to be effective.

Please note `maxsize=None` which is going to ensure the limit of cache size is much larger than the default 128 (and restricted only by the RAM size).

### Own implementation of the cache

`lru_cache` does not offer flexibility to cache the result depending on the return value of the function. However, you can easily implement it yourself using `set`:

```
cache = set()

def is_exist(link :str) -> bool:
    if query_db(link) is True:
         return True
    return False

def process(link: str)
   if link in cache:
      return True

   if is_exist(link) is True:
       cache.add(link)
       return
```

Comment: when query_db return False If the same link come again the link need be processed once again.

Comment: @shaocong Do you want to have both an `is_exist` and and `is_processed` to avoid duplicate processing?

Answer (score 0):

You need the test for the link and if it doesn't exist then create it in the same call - probably simplest to get rid of a cached is_exists and cache the process() function, but rename it to e.g. ensure_link:

```
@lru_cache
def ensure_link(link: str)
   if query_db(link) is True:
       return
   # do something
   # put result to database
   return
```

Either that or do the caching yourself in a function attribute or similar - it's not very difficult

Comment: you answer helped me. but when executing ensure_link fail may be happened. implement cache by myself in accepted. if python offers lru_cache  container with query and put method will be very good.

Comment: You can just use a `dict` for this purpose, unless you think that you are actually going to fill the cache. The implementation question is then just where it will be stored. A global? A function attribute?